# How to constrain stack view between two objects

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

I need an `imageview` to always be exactly halfway between two other objects in the view. The way I tried to resolve this was by putting that `imageview` in a stack view, and then trying to constrain the stack view top and bottom spacing as 0 to the objects.

However, the stack view does not change size so that the top and bottom touch the objects, I just get an error. What's the best way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a view instead of a stack view. Then you can resize it to however size you want based on constraints.